# PHP - How can regex replace a string by condition

Tags: php, regex, replace, conditional-statements

I have a string:

```
{include "abc"}

{literal} 

function xyz() {

       "ok";

   }

{/literal}

{abc}

{123 }
```

I just want to replace all `{` to `{{` and `}` to `}}` not in `{literal}` tag. The result will be:

```
{{include "abc"}}

{{literal}}

   function xyz() {

       "ok";

   }

   //... something contain { and }

{{/literal}}

{{abc}}

{123 }}
```

Someone can help me, Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Is it just me, or is this another X-Y problem? Why are you turning to regex for this? It looks to me like you're trying to parse something

Comment: Oh, I try to parse smarty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?s)(?<=\{literal\}).*?(?=\{\/literal\})(*SKIP)(*F)|([{}])
```

Replacement string:

```
\1\1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uF9eM9/1)

Comment: Thank you so much, It's work for me. I think you are master of regex :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~(?:(?<={literal})[^{]*(?:{(?!/literal})[^{]*)*+|[^{}]*)([{}])\K~'

$text = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $text);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sY5vU8/2)

pattern details:

```
~                       # pattern delimiter
(?:                     # non-capturing group
    (?<={literal})      # lookbehind: preceded by "{literal}"
                        # a lookbehind doesn't capture any thing, it is only a test
    [^{]*               # all that is not a {
    (?:
        {(?!/literal})  #/# a { not followed by "/literal}"
        [^{]*
    )*+                 # repeat as needed
  |                     # OR
    [^{}]*              # all that is not a curly bracket,
                        # (to quickly reach the next curly bracket)
)
([{}])                  # capture a { or a } in group 1
\K                      # discards all on the left from match result
                        # (so the whole match is empty and nothing is replaced,
                        # the content of the capture group is only added 
                        # with the replacement string '$1')
~
```

Notes: this pattern assumes that `{literal}` can't be nested and always closed. If `{literal}` can stay unclosed, it is possible to force this default behavior: *"an unclosed `{literal}` is considered as open until the end of the string"*.

To do that you can change the capture group to `([{}]|(*COMMIT)(*F))`. When the first branch `[{}]` fails, this means that the end of the string is reached. The `(*COMMIT)` verb forces the regex engine to stop all research in the string when the pattern fails after, and `(*F)` forces it to fail. So all after `{literal}` stay unchanged.